# Is it possible to have different Xcode themes based on the current file type or language?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, syntax-highlighting

I'm wanting to change my current syntax coloring if I'm editing a Swift file and have the coloring change when I change languages (from Swift to Objective C, say) when changing tabs or windows or what-have-you.  Is this possible in Xcode 5 or 6?